# How do I calculate the Time Difference in Excel when a filter is active?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i have these data for example:

[image]

as you can see the filter is on "Fahrzeugname". Now i want to calculate the Time Difference of each line. If I use

```
=A4-A2
```

the first line does calculate the right time and if i append that on the next lines it uses:

```
=A6-A4
```

which should be A7

Could you help me there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula in `F2` under "Zeitdifferenz":

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/(D3:D$100=D2),A3:A$100)-A2
```

You should change the 100 rows reference into whichever you need it to be. I made this answer under the assumption you always filter for just a single "Fahrzeugname". Otherwise, you could create an helper column where you check if a cell is visible in the first place, for example using `=SUBTOTAL(3,A2)`. Then you can use the same formula as above but instead of referencing the D-column, you should reference the helper column and check against the value of 1.